# Cyclic transfer of Object

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm trying to model blood flow. As simple as it gets I am trying to have an event (TimerTick) trigger the transfer of a resource object from unit A to unit B, B's to C, C's to A. I can't seem to have reproducible transfer of the resources from one iteration to another, and I've tried a lot more of different ways than what's pasted below. 
The units are connected as a triangle after construction. I'm aware that this leaves the first unit to be erroneous, and have tried numerous ways to deal with it (and I'm not sure if that is the only problem) but since none have worked I won't post them.
An idea of event set-up where any one unit doesn't need to know about any others would be totally appreciated. But just a way to make this work would also be appreciated.

```
class Unit{    
Resource currentResource;
Resource incomingResource;
Unit preUnit;
Unit postUnit;
public Unit( int resource, Timer t)
    {
        this.currentResource = new Resource(resource);
        t.TimerTick += T_TimerTick;
    }
 private void T_TimerTick(object sender, TimerTickEventArgs e)
    {
        postUnit.receiveResource(currentResource);
        currentResource = incomingResource;
}
void receiveResource(Resource resource)
    {
        incomingResource = resource;
    }
//pre and post units connected appropriately to Cycle ...-A-B-C-A-...
// with one cycle per TimerTick
}
```

Comment: i've added an approach & a sample. Maybe you can also tag 'design patterns' in your question for it to receive more attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest Inversion of control with Observer pattern

Here is a working setup, to explain my suggestion. In my code, each unit just increments the resource by 1.

And gererates the following output

*Initiating Unit A value 1

Unit A, output 1

Unit B, input 1

Unit B, output 2

Unit C, input 2

Unit C, output 3

Unit A, input 3

Unit A, Cycle complete*

client code

```
      IInitiatorUnit A = new InitiatorUnit("A");
        IUnit B = new Unit("B");
        IUnit C = new Unit("C");

        B.RegisterUnit(A); // B is listening to A
        C.RegisterUnit(B); // C is listening to B
        A.RegisterUnit(C); //  A is listinig to C


 void heartBeatTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        A.GenerateResource(1); // Start the process
    }
```

I have designed unit such that it takes an input, processes it & fires an event for

```
     interface IUnit
    {
        event EventHandler<ResourceGeneratedEventArgs> ResourceGenerated;
        void RegisterUnit(IUnit inputUnit);
        string Name { get; }
    }

    class Unit : IUnit
    {

        IUnit mInputUnit;
        public event EventHandler<ResourceGeneratedEventArgs> ResourceGenerated;
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public Unit(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public void RegisterUnit(IUnit inputUnit)
        {
            this.mInputUnit = inputUnit;
            this.mInputUnit.ResourceGenerated += mInputUnitResourceGenrated;
        }

        void mInputUnitResourceGenrated(object sender, ResourceGeneratedEventArgs inputResource)
        {
           //take the input resorce. pocess it & fire the event;
            //I'm just adding 1 to it as sample

            int outputResource = inputResource.Resource + 1;

            Console.WriteLine("Unit {0}, input {1} ", this.Name, inputResource.Resource, outputResource);

            OnResourceGenerated(outputResource);
        }      

        protected virtual void OnResourceGenerated(int outputResource)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unit {0}, output {1}", this.Name,  outputResource);

             if (ResourceGenerated != null)
                ResourceGenerated(this, new ResourceGeneratedEventArgs(outputResource));
        }
    }


    public class ResourceGeneratedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public ResourceGeneratedEventArgs(int resource)
        {
            Resource = resource;
        }

        public int Resource { get; private set; }
    } 



     /// <summary>
     /// This is just to start the process here, Nothing great here 
     /// </summary>
     interface IInitiatorUnit : IUnit
     {
        void  GenerateResource(int initialValue);
     }


    class InitiatorUnit : Unit, IInitiatorUnit
    {
        //prevents the cycle from going on & on
        bool resetFlag;

        public InitiatorUnit(string name):base(name)
        {

        }

        public void GenerateResource(int initialValue)
        {
            resetFlag = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Initiating Unit {0} value {1}", this.Name, initialValue);
            OnResourceGenerated(initialValue);
        }

        protected override void OnResourceGenerated(int outputResource)
        {
            //Dont raise the event. if the cycle has completed
            if (resetFlag == false)
            {
                resetFlag = true;
                base.OnResourceGenerated(outputResource);
            }
            else
            {
                //do nothing, cycle has completed
                Console.WriteLine("Unit {0}, Cycle complete", this.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

### Edit 1 : Approach for very large number of units

In my 1st approach, each unit called the subsequent one creating a chain, something like this - [image]

As the nodes would increase so would be the depth of call stack, therefore when the number reaches in thousands we can overrun the stack limit causing a stack over flow.

Therefore the new approach is a just uses an iterates over the units, giving each unit a request, getting a response back and feeding the response to the subsequent unit as request. Something like this -

[image]

Here is a working sample & it generates the following output -

Unit A, input 0
Unit A, output 1
Unit B, input 1
Unit B, output 2
Unit C, input 2
Unit C, output 3
Cycle completed result 3

Client Code

```
private void ClientCode()
    {
        // Create an array of units 
        IUnit[] units = new IUnit[] {
            new Unit("A"), // A will be called 1st . It needs to be given an initial value to start processing
            new Unit("B"), // B will get A's Output to process. 
            new Unit("C"), // C will get B's Output to process. 
        };

        // pass the array to workflow to process 
        cycle = new WorkFlow(units);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Heart beat timer

```
  void heartBeatTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = cycle.Execute(new Resource(0)); // starting the cycle with initial value of 0

        Console.WriteLine("Cycle completed result {0}", result.Value); 
    }
```

The infrastructure is much simpler now,

```
    interface IUnit
    {
        Resource ProcessResource(Resource inputResource);
        string Name { get; }
    }

    class Unit : IUnit
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public Unit(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public Resource ProcessResource(Resource inputResource)
        {
            //take the input resorce. pocess it & fire the event;
            //I'm just adding 1 to it as sample

            int outputResource = inputResource.Value + 1;

            Console.WriteLine("Unit {0}, input {1} ", this.Name, inputResource.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Unit {0}, output {1} ", this.Name, outputResource);


            return new Resource(outputResource);
        }
    }


    class WorkFlow
    {
        IUnit[] mUnits;

        public WorkFlow(IUnit[] units)
        {
            this.mUnits = units;
        }

        public Resource Execute(Resource initiatingResource)
        {
            Resource result = initiatingResource; // initialise result with the input of the cycle.
            for (int i = 0; i < mUnits.Length; i++)
            {
                // the result is passed as input. 
                //IUnit.ProcessResource function gives back a new result which is encached as input for subsequent resource
                result = mUnits[i].ProcessResource(result);
            }
            return result; // after all are processed, 
        }
    }

    public class Resource
    {
        public Resource(int resourceValue)
        {
            Value = resourceValue;
        }

        public int Value { get; private set; }
    }
```

Hope all will work fine now. Please write me a comment if any bit is unclear.

Comment: This looks like it should do everything I need it to do. I will let you know when I extrapolate it, but thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to know it serves yr purpose. Please write me a comment if you think any changes or enhancements are needed to this solution.

Comment: In applying your solution, the problem I  ran into is that when I raise the event from a unit, as in your code: 'OnResourceGenerated(...);', the event gets raised, with its respective eventHandlers attached to it being called (to transfer the object to the next unit), and then that unit raises its event, etc., but we never really return to the 'mInputUnitResourceGenrated' function to close it out (in your case the function is essentially done after 'OnResourceGenerated(...);', but I do one more thing) until all events are launched. Thus, I end up with a stackOverflowException. Thoughts?

Comment: @Void, if it becomes a **cycle** of event handlers we'll run into stackOverflowException. In my example, its the `InitiatorUnit` which breaks this cycle. From your problem description I assume that the other step you are performing is creating another sub-cycle. Is this correct ? So lets say Main cycle is  A-> B-> C ->A.  But B starts a sub-cycle before calling C.  A -> B-> B1 -> B2 -> B3 -> B1 -> C ? Could you please elaborate the additional step that you are doing the one you have mentioned as *"but I do one more thing"*. So I'll can see the problem at my end too.

Comment: I don't believe it is so much related to it being an endless cycle as it is the fact that I have many many more units than 3 (probably going to be closer to 1000). Thus, even within one cycle, I ended up with the stackOverflow. The other thing that I do is save the resource to the unit (which your solution does not do, but I don't believe that that is what is causing the exception), and pass the unit's old resource onto the next unit (which your solution does do, and I believe the exception comes from this). I am not entirely sure though and am open to suggestion.

Comment: I looked into making a larger stack than is the default, but I feel like that is just avoiding the problem (and I didn't really find anything in C# or within my level of comprehension). So what I ended up doing last night was report the resource to some 'otherObject', which saves it, and then the event finishes. The 'otherObject' also has a 'while(cycleRunning)' that is executed by the 'initiatorUnit' (after the event finishes), and raises the next event for 'savedUnit'. It looks promising, but I haven't finished it and am not certain if the while loop continues to run && doesn't block?

Comment: @Void, alright... as I understand we have a situation where the the number of units will run in 1000s. I'll make a design change, better suited for such a case. At the moment I have to leave for work, but I'll give the solution today.

Comment: @Void, I've added a different design approach & a sample working code, and I have also explained the conceptual difference in both the approaches.... I regret I didn't realize you were dealing such a huge number of units at first place. But this simpler one shall scale very fine.

Comment: Very cool, I think this is something similar to what I mentioned I started doing. I will look over it and let you know later this week. Appreciate the extra mile you're going through.

Comment: @Void, Hi did u get a chance to try the new approach ? does it solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Are those elements and method named, Unit, within a class which is also named Unit?

Try moving the methods and elements to another class.

I would make three static classes for your units:

```
public static class UnitA
{
    var foo1;
    var foo2;
}

public static class UnitB
{
    var foo1;
    var foo2;
}

public static class UnitC
{
    var foo1;
    var foo2;
}
```

For each tic, you can handle the resources from any other class:

```
FooHandler_Tick
{
    // Store C's content.
    var tempFoo1 = UnitC.foo1;
    var tempFoo2 = UnitC.foo2;

    // B to C.
    UnitC.foo1 = UnitB.foo1;
    UnitC.foo2 = UnitB.foo2;

    // A to B.
    UnitB.foo1 = UnitA.foo1;
    UnitB.foo2 = UnitA.foo2;

    // C to A.
    UnitC.foo1 = tempFoo1;
    UnitC.foo2 = tempFoo2;
}
```

Does this work with your project?

Comment: Thanks, but with like several hundred arteries, veins, and organs, I don't think several hundred static classes (most of which with identical function) with global access would work very well. It is a nifty thought though.